# I wasn't notified I earned the Disciplined badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, top-bar, achievements-dialog

I removed an answer of mine with 4 upvotes.

Therefore, I was awarded the Discipline badge:

[image]

However, I wasn't notified:

[image]

Usually I am notified when I earn badges, so this seems a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Silver and gold badges are always considered veteran-worthy, so you'll always be notified of those.
>
> On real child metas (that excludes Meta Stack Exchange), you're always considered a veteran; on all other sites, you're considered a veteran if you have received the association bonus, i.e. you have 200 rep somewhere.
>
> The following bronze badges are considered veteran-worthy:
>
> - Nice Answer
> - Nice Question
> - Caucus
> - Excavator
> - Mortarboard
> - Popular Question
> - Proofreader
> - Revival
> - Synonymizer
> - Tumbleweed
> - Vox Populi
> - Announcer
> - Precognitive
> - Curious
> - any tag-based bronze badge
>
> **Any bronze badge not in this list is not veteran-worthy i.e. won't cause a notification for veteran users.**

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/293416)