# Why don't I get a notification about a new badge on Meta?

Tags: support, badges, meta

Why don't I get a notification about an earned badge on Meta?

Comment: Probably this is like [I wasn't notified I earned the Disciplined badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305427/1529630)

Comment: @oriol : he is asking about Disciplined badge but it's a general question mine

Comment: @Stijn yes, because it's what the *question* is about. Tags categorize the question, not the answer.

Comment: @Emna, still, I'm inclined to close it as a duplicate. The answer there still applies.

Comment: By the way @Emna, if your (now deleted) question about duplicate and score is for THIS question..... you don't get or lose rep on Meta :).

Comment: Regarding your (recently deleted) question: [MSE: What happens with reputation earned on a closed question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53397/what-happens-with-reputation-earned-on-a-closed-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get notifications for *some* of the bronze badges, particularly those which are easy to obtain, like Editor and Student. This is irrespective of whether you are on the main site or on meta.

The details are mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! because i'm beginner in meta site but experienced  in the main site

Comment: Welcome to Meta!